# OpenAPI Generator / Swagger Codegen: How to add a function after all files have been generated

Tags: java, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm trying to add a hook after all the files are created by the Go client generator and I'm wondering where I can add this.

Right now, files are generated in this order (a) models (b) API paths (c) supporting files.

If I hook into `AbstractGoCodegen`'s `postProcessSupportingFileData` function like so, `myfunc()` will get called before the supporting files like `README.md` and `client.go` are created, but I want the function be called afterwards.

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> postProcessSupportingFileData(Map<String, Object> objs) {
    generateYAMLSpecFile(objs);
    objs = super.postProcessSupportingFileData(objs);
    myfunc();
    return objs;
}
```

I've also tried a few other other `postProcessing*` functions as shown in `DefaultCodegen` but they didn't work as desired.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get the desired functionality from overriding the configuration methods, I suggest that you extend the `DefaultGenerator` class. These contain the actual generation methods such as `generateSupportingFiles`. You should be able to easily add your hook after this method has generated the supporting files.

Keep in mind that you might have to change a few modifiers from private to protected.